# F# Array.FindIndex exception handling

Tags: arrays, sorting, exception, collections, f#

I have the following function that finds the Index in an Array

```
let numbers_array = [| "1"; "2"; "3"|]
let findIndex arr elem = arr |> Array.findIndex ((=) elem)

let s = "123"
findIndex numbers_array (string s.[0]))
```

However if i try to run

`findIndex numbers_array (string s.[10]))`

it is out of bounds and throws the following error

*System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: An index satisfying the predicate was not found in the collection.*

How can i make my function so instead of throwing the exception it does something instead like a printf statement?

Comment: I believe there is a tryFindIndex.

Comment: tryFindIndex returns an option type, which i can't use

Comment: Why can't you use options? You can catch the `KeyNotFoundException` but you'll still have to decide what to return in the error case.

Comment: The question contains errors that should be corrected. The source is not compilable. Nor does it demonstrate the error in italics. The out of bounds error mentioned occurs in the argument to the function, and so is not relevant.

Comment: `tryFindIndex` is definitely the right thing to use. If you don't want to change the signature of your function, you can `printf` in case `tryFindIndex` returns `None`, and then return -1. (See below for a proposed answer based on this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is close to what you want:

```
let findIndex arr elem =
    match arr |> Array.tryFindIndex ((=) elem) with
        | Some index -> index
        | None ->
            printfn "Not found"
            -1
```

It maintains the same function signature you have now, and generates an error message as a side-effect if the element isn't found. (Note that the function still has to return an `int` in this case, so I've chosen -1.)